# When typing a new function, the {} combination opens up all folds (vim)

Tags: vim, code-folding

I'm using the following

```
:set foldmethod=syntax
```

And after I close two folds with `zc`

[image: folds closed]

Then proceed to write a new function, immediately after I close the block with a curly bracket `}` (I do this in the `INSERT` mode), all folds open up

[image]

This seems annoying, how do I stop this behaviour?

Comment: Just so you know, the "create fold" command is "`zf`" while the "close existing fold" command is "`zc`". Also, when `'foldmenthod'` is set to "`syntax`" you cannot create folds with "`zf`".

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say I used `zc` to close folds, not create them. Typo. Thanks for noticing @Heptite

Comment: [Not posted as an answer because someone might have a solution.] The problem here is that in this context Vim's folding is based on syntax rules, and when you add a new top-level `{`, it makes the blocks (functions) that were considered folds look like sub-blocks within your new function until you add a `}`, so the folds get zapped then recreated, causing them to open on you.